# VBA: How to copy part of the string from one cell and replace part of another cell with it?

Tags: vba, excel

The text in excel I have looks like this:

[tab]SECTION 01.
*Name of section 1
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
[tab]SECTION 2.
*Name of section 2
TEXT
...

I want to find next SECTION in column (1, 2, 3...), copy only string SECTION 01. (02., 03.,...,52.,...)and paste it in the cell below replacing only *.

The end result in excel should look like this:

SECTION 01. Name of section 1
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
SECTION 02. Name of section 2
TEXT
...

I tried to record macro, but it only copies the same text to only one cell specified, so I will have to rearrange VB code. Can anyone help?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service. You will find that you will receive prompt and eager responses to your problem once you demonstrate some effort of having tried to resolve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code iterates column `a` (`col`=1) and when it finds a '[tab]' it sets the `sctn` variable to the value of the cell (ignoring the '[tab]')

When it finds a '*', it replaces it with the content of the `sctn` variable

```
Dim row as Integer,col as Integer,sctn as String
col=1
row=1
While Cells(row,col)<>""
  If Instr(Cells(row,col),"[tab]")>0 Then
    sctn=Replace(Cells(row,col),"[tab]","")
    Cells(row,col)=sctn
  Else
    Cells(row,col)=Replace(Cells(row,col),"*",sctn)
  End If
  row=row+1
Wend
```

Comment: I wanted to vote-up but I don't have the reputation!